# Convert value from string to generic type that is either Guid or int

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, casting

I've got a generic method which converts an id from a string (eg, retrieved from the Value of a HiddenField on an ASP.NET Form) to a target type and does something with it.

```
private void MyMethod<T>(string rawId, Action<T> doSomethingWithId)
{
    T id = (T)Convert.ChangeType(rawId, typeof(T));
    doSomethingWithId(id);
}
```

T will be either Guid or Int32 and the above code falls over (at runtime) when it is Guid, saying that the cast from String to Guid is invalid.

Then I thought I might try to check the type and if Guid, instantiate a new Guid:

```
var id = default(T);
if (id is Guid)
    id = new Guid(rawId);
else
    id = (T)Convert.ChangeType(rawId, typeof(T));
```

now this gives an error (at compile time) that Guid cannot be converted to type T

Not too sure how to work around this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

the below code works fine with conversion to Guid . check it

```
id = (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromInvariantString(text);
```

Answer (score 3):

If `T` will either be `Guid` or `Int32` then it's not *really* very generic, is it? Just write two methods instead - either with different names, or *possibly* overloads. I don't see the benefit in using generics here, and it may very well make your code more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: You're right, but this is a bit of a contrived example, there's more to that method and it does simplify things in the broader context of what I'm doing.

Comment: @Veli: This is why it's worth being careful when you write a question, and giving a representative picture. I would still consider splitting it into two public non-generic methods which might use a common generic private method as *part* of the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this perhaps:

```
private void MyMethod<T>(string rawId, Action<T> doSomethingWithId)
{
    T id = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { rawId });
    doSomethingWithId(id);
}
```